# Can you use the Fourier series PDE solution method for Dirichlet (or Neumann) boundary conditions?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-series, boundary-value-problem

I understand that there is a method which can be used to solve PDEs wherein you assume a function has a Fourier series representation to get rid of spatial derivatives. For example, if I consider Poisson's equation on a rectangle I can write:
\begin{equation}
\nabla^2 \varphi = f(x, y) \\
\implies \left( \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2} \right) \sum_{k_x, k_y} \hat{\varphi}_{k_x, k_y} e^{i(k_x x + k_y y)} = \sum_{k_x, k_y} \hat{f}_{k_x, k_y} e^{i(k_x x + k_y y)} \\
\implies \left( k_x^2 + k_y^2 \right)\hat{\varphi}_{k_x, k_y} = \hat{f}_{k_x, k_y} \\
\implies \varphi(x, y) = \sum_{k_x, k_y} \frac{\hat{f}_{k_x, k_y}}{k_x^2 + k_y^2}
\end{equation}
where $k_x = 2\pi n/L_x$ and $k_y = 2\pi m/L_y$ for domain side lengths $L_x$ and $L_y$ and integers $m$, $n$. Then we may solve for $\varphi(x, y)$ in a specific case by doing some Fourier integrals. I have been told that this works if the functions involved are periodic, which I have taken to mean $f(x, 0) = f(x, L_y)$ and $f(0, y) = f(L_x, y)$ for all $x$ and $y$.

Can this scheme work with Dirichlet (or Neumann) boundary conditions? If so, where do we take these into account? If not, are there any similar techniques that will work with these boundary conditions? I have seen something about these half-range Fourier series, but it seems like you need to know whether your function is even/odd (or neither) a priori.

I have tried the specific example of $\varphi$ being $0$ at the boundaries. In this case, if we take $x = 0$ we get
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k_x, k_y} \hat{\varphi}_{k_x, k_y} e^{ik_y y} = 0
\end{equation}
Operating on both sides with $\int_0^{L_y} e^{-i k_y' y}dy$ yields:
\begin{equation}
L_y\sum_{k_x} \hat{\varphi}_{k_x, k_y'} = 0
\end{equation}
for all $k_y'$. Similarly, we may calculate
\begin{equation}
L_x\sum_{k_y} \hat{\varphi}_{k_x', k_y} = 0
\end{equation}
for all $k_x'$. It's not really clear to me how I can use this information to solve for $\hat{\varphi}_{k_x, k_y}$ or even whether these conditions are compatible with the Laplace equation solution for $\hat{\varphi}_{k_x, k_y}$.

Comment: While this may not be precisely what you're asking about, it's more conventional to use the sine basis and the cosine basis in the Dirichlet / Neumann problems respectively. Imposing boundary conditions amounts to restricting attention from the full space of functions to the kernel of a particular linear map (one which is rather unwieldy in the standard Fourier basis). The sine / cosine series are a simple set of coordinates for this subspace.

Comment: @Kajelad when you say "sine and cosine" basis, in 2D are you talking about the basis formed by the following products: $\sin(k_x x)\sin(k_y y)$, $\sin(k_x x)\cos(k_y y)$, $\cos(k_x x)\sin(k_y y)$, $\cos(k_x x)\cos(k_y y)$? Or would you also include the half-range functions like $\sin(m\pi x/L_x)\sin(n\pi y/L_y)$? And even then, how would you go about imposing the boundary conditions? At some point I tried to get it to work out using the orthogonality conditions, and I think I came up with some nonsense.

Comment: By the sine basis, I mean $$\sin\left(\frac{m\pi x}{L_x}\right)\sin\left(\frac{n\pi y}{L_y}\right)\ \ \ \ \ n,m\in\mathbb{N}$$ This basis is orthogonal with respect to the $L^2$ inner product, and any linear combination of them satisfies Dirichlet boundary conditions.

Comment: Likewise, for the Neumann problem one can use the basis $$\cos\left(\frac{m\pi x}{L_x}\right)\cos\left(\frac{n\pi y}{L_y}\right)\ \ \ \ \ n,m\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}$$ These are also orthogonal, and any linear combination satisfies Neumann boundary conditions, provided it converges sufficiently rapidly to commute the sum and derivative.